# UIImageView in custom cell not working as it should

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have placed an UIImageView in a custom cell which only has that UIImageView as it's subview.
I have added these constraints:

[image]

[image]

Now I have set clipsToBounds for both ImageView and it's container (parent - content view) equal to true. Image content mode is set to aspect to fit.
But when I set the image from `cellForRowAt` function ImageView ignores the clipsToBounds and constraints. I see this in execution:
[image]

As you can see none have the image aspect to fit nor setted constraint.
I have gave the row height in `heightForRowAt` function and even used the `estimatedHeightForRowAt` function as well.

Comment: check your image view content mode

Comment: Dear @masoud I forgot to mention it in the question... It's set to aspect to fit. I will edit the question right now.

Comment: @AfshinM.Khiabani set your image to aspect to fill or Scale to fill may be it will help. i think your image is to small to set so that's why it's not coming on full frame.

Comment: @AfshinM.Khiabani no problem bro, change your image view content mode to aspects to fill

Comment: @VipinPareek I have tried with different image sizes and content modes. It's looks like the contant mode and clips to bounds are ignores... By the way I load the images from image array. They are not in my Assets (Just giving extra info. It might help)

Comment: your constraints are breaking brother

Comment: @AfshinM.Khiabani just open your storyboard and click on your image view and then select aspects to fill from storyboard then run and check.

Comment: If you've got a fixed inset for top, bottom, leading and trailing, you don't need the constraint centering the image. Less is more when it comes to constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the UITableViewCell already has an ImageView in it named imageView and my custom image view had the same name. When I was trying to set the image in it the default imageView of the cell got the image instead of my own UIImageView.
I changed the name of my imageView to ImgThumb and put the image in it and worked perfectly.